# Mark Duplicate in Access

Tags: ms-access, duplicates

I would like to write a query in Access 2013 to mark the first time a word appears as "Yes" and all subsequent times as "No". I have included a sample below. The "Distinct" column is what I would like my query to generate.

Thank you

---

```
Word      Distinct
First     Yes
Second    Yes
First     No
Third     Yes
```

Comment: Are there any additional fields used as a primary key? How is the data sorted?

Comment: Depending on your purpose in marking duplicate values, you might want to consider aggregate queries using the `Group By` clause and other aggregate SQL functions like `COUNT` to find and/or process duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```
SELECT *, IIf(DMin("ID","Table1","[Word]='" & [Word] & "'")=[ID],"Yes","No") AS FirstWord
FROM Table1;
```

Another:

```
SELECT *, IIf([ID] = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Table1 AS Dupe WHERE Dupe.Word = Table1.Word ORDER BY Dupe.Word, Dupe.ID), "Yes", "No") AS FirstWord FROM Table1;
```

DISTINCT is a reserved word so I am avoiding using it as a field name.

Comment: This of course assumes that there is a single-column Primary Key [ID] and that the data source will be a table, neither of which was indicated by the OP.  In either query, you should also `ORDER BY [ID]` to ensure that the first occurrence really is sorted first.  (Even if it is likely to be sorted on ID, it is not guaranteed unless it is specified in the ORDER BY clause.  This is especially true if the source object is not a table directly, rather another query.)

Comment: Even if not already present, ID field easy to add with autonumber. Cross-posted at http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=65965